# in node.js express app, req.body does not get <textarea> value?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, textarea

I am working with an express app in node.js. I have the following html form (inputForm.html):

```
<form action="/" method="post">
Name: <br>
    <input type="text" name="name" size="45">
    <br>
    Document: <br>
    <textarea> <input type="text" name="document" size="45"> </textarea>
    <br>
    <br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

and the following javascript file:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(bodyParser.json({type: 'application/vnd.api+json' }));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {

  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/" + "inputForm.html");

});

app.post('/', function (req, res) {

    var name = req.body.name;
    var document = req.query.document;

    console.log(req.body);

});
```

However, only the first value (name) shows up when I print req.body to the console. If I remove the textarea tag, the document also shows up. However, I want to leave it because I want to preserve natural line breaks in the document input. Anyone know what I need to do to fix this?

Thanks so much!

Comment: `<textarea> <input type="text" name="document" size="45"> </textarea>` doesn't make any sense. The content of the `textarea` should be the text for its default value, not an `input` element.

Comment: Please [learn to love labels](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/)

Answer (score 2):

`document` is part of the text of the default **value** of the textarea.

The textarea itself doesn't have a `name`, so it can't be a successful control and won't submit any data to the server.

Give it a name.

```
<textarea name="document"> &lt;input type=&quot;text&quot; name=&quot;document&quot; size=&quot;45&quot;&gt; </textarea>
```